# Referencing a file using Get-Item causes the file to be locked later in the script can't get around it

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script that accesses files, reading from them, writing to new files etc.

The process starts by checking a folder for a file.

`$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\file\*" -Filter "*.txt"`

It then sends the file to a separate function `Split-File file`

This function reads each line of the file:

`Foreach($lines in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($file.FullName)) {`

It then reads the content of that file, skips a set amount of lines and then outputs the rest to a separate file in a different folder.

`$file | Select-Object -Skip $amount | Out-File "C:\path\to\different\folder\$name" -Append`

However, it gets to that final stage and outputs the error:

````
'C:\path\to\different\folder\$file.Name' because it is     
being used by another process.
At C:\path\to\script\.ps1
+ ... p $amount | Out-File "C:\path\to\different\folder\$file.Name ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand```
````

How do I prevent this file being locked, the file is not referenced anywhere else but the given lines above.

The 'Main'

```
switch($newFile) {
    # A new file is waiting to be counted and split
    $true {
        Write-Output("New file found!")
        # Set the filepath to look at the new file
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\new\file" -Filter "*.txt" -

        Get-SplitSize # Figure out how many leads to load per day
        Split-Files $file # Split the files and then load them
    }
    # An already split file is loaded
    $false {
        Write-Output("No new file found...")
        # Set the filepath to look at the old already split file
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\old\file\*" -Filter "*.txt"

        Split-Files $file # Split the files and then load them
    }
}
```

The Split-File function

```
function Split-Files($file) {
    # Get the content of the file
    $volume = 0
    $records = 0

    $name = $file.Name
    $filePath = $file.FullName

    # Get the volume of leads to load
    Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\another\file | ForEach-Object {
        # Read the volume amount
        foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\path\to\another\file")) {
            if($line.Contains("Data per day this week: ")) {
                $volume = $line.Replace("Data per day this week: ", "")
                break
            }
        }
    }
    # Variables
    $volume = [Math]::Floor($volume) # Round down the total volume
    $amount = 0 # Amount of lines read
    $finished = $false # Indicates if the process s finished

    # For each line of data in the given file
    Foreach($lines in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($file.FullName)) {
        $amount++ # A line has been read
        $lines | Out-File "C:\path\to\file\$name" -Append # Output each line into a split file

        # If the current variable is the last lead in the list
        if($lines.Contains("STRING")) {
            $records++ # A record has been completed

            # If the amount of records processed is the same as the volume to load
            if($records -eq $volume) {
                $finished = $true # The action is now complete
            }
        }

        # Break out of the loop
        if($finished) {
            break
        }
    }
    # Output the remaining leads from file into a separate file to be read from later   
    $file | Select-Object -Skip $amount | Out-File "C:\path\to\different\folder\$name" -Append
}
```

I had originally thought it was due to the foreach loop, but from my understanding I've broken out of the file using `break`

Can I close an open file using `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem` in a way like `$file.Close`??

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you see the filename in the error? `C:\path\to\script\.ps1` - if you tried to sanitize and mistyped, please correct. Otherwise, you are trying to write to a file named `.ps1`?

Comment: @DougMaurer sanitising and also just showing theres a powershell script in that folder

Comment: It's saying it can't write to the ps1.. are you intending to write to a ps1?

Comment: It's saying it can't write to a file from that .ps1 script, not that the .ps1 isn't being able to be written too

Comment: @DougMaurer ah I see what you mean

Comment: Is the file name in error message on your screen literally ```'C:\path\to\different\folder\$file.Name'```? It looks like something isn’t doing variable expansion properly (maybe you’ve used single quotes around a string instead of double-quotes?) so every file is trying to write to that same literal path…

Comment: @mclayton no it's sanitisation